# Difference between Chroma.afrom_texts and Chroma.from_texts

Tags: python, langchain, chromadb

I am working with langchain and ChromaDB in python and I see that I have two options when creating the vectorestore:

```
db = Chroma.afrom_texts(docs, embedding_function)
```

This first one returns: `db = <coroutine object VectorStore.afrom_texts at 0x00000258DCDDF680>`

```
db = Chroma.from_texts(docs, embedding_function)
```

And the second one: `db= <langchain.vectorstores.chroma.Chroma at 0x258dcf80b20>`

I guess the second one is the normal one, but has anyone used the first one? Anyone knows what is that `<coroutine object VectorStore.afrom_texts at 0x00000258DCDDF680>`.

Besides. Is there a way to visualize the vectors, the numbers. I would like to explore a little bit.
Thank you in advanced!

Just a learning question

Answer (score 2):

`Chroma.from_texts()` returns an instance of the `Chroma` class and is synchronous (and can be called as any other method in your code), while `Chroma.afrom_texts()` returns a [coroutine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) which means is asynchronous and needs to be awaited for as it runs "in the background":

```py
db = await Chroma.afrom_texts()
```

Comment: I see, thank you:)